# How to load 2 different WFS layers using OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, web-mapping, openlayers-2, jquery

I've been trying to load 2 WFS layers with the 3857 projection and I'm only able to load one of them, a line vector layer, while the other (point vector) doesn't load at all.

Later I'm going to want to edit both layers in the web app but for now I'm just trying to get them both to load

The code I'm using to load them is:

```
var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
  var url1 =    'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
    'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=BFTchambers:bft2&' +
    'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures' +
    '&bbox=' + extent.join(',');
$.ajax({url: url1, dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: false})
    .done(function(response) {
        formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS(),
        sourceVector.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response))
        });
},
strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
maxZoom: 20
})),
});

var vectorSource2 = new ol.source.Vector({
loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
  var url2 =    'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
    'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=BFTchambers:chamber&' +
    'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures' +
    '&bbox=' + extent.join(',');
$.ajax({url: url2, dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: false})
    .done(function(response) {
        pointWFS = new ol.format.WFS(),
        sourceVector2.addFeatures(pointWFS.readFeatures(response))
        });
},
strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
maxZoom: 20
})),
});


/**
 * JSONP WFS callback function.
 * @param {Object} response The response object.
*/
window.loadFeatures = function(response) {
console.log("some stuff loaded");
vectorSource.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
vectorSource2.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
};

selectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
});

var layerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: vectorSource,
style: new ol.style.Style({
image: new ol.style.Circle({
stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
  width: 5
  })
})
})
});

var layerVector2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: vectorSource2,
style: new ol.style.Style({
stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
  color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
  width: 2
})
})
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
imagerySet: 'Road',
key: 'AsBPC3VYKwiu_XhkUWVqfNQGC6upeSXaFwwVyN9SdMEu8znuAtNkymIX9xzRTfs6'
})
});

var map = new ol.Map({
layers: [raster, layerVector, layerVector2],
target: document.getElementById('map'),
view: new ol.View({
center: [-12000,6711790],   
zoom: 12
})
});
```

Only the layerVector loads, not the layerVector2. How to fix the code?

Entire fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Luffydude/2c5o284v/

Comment: Hi there, I think you should make 2 different window.loadFeatures one for the linestrings and the other for the points

Comment: Hey Hicham man! I've managed to fix my code :)

Comment: Hey Luffydude Sorry I couldn't read your comment in time, good thing that you managed to solve it, could you please post it as an answer so that it may help others who got the same problem. Cheers

Comment: The code posted below by pavlos worked, but I just needed to add a few codes of style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is a bit complicated concering your `callback:loadFeatures` function. Within the function you add features for both requests to both sources. 
Try to distinguis them using two separate functions and see if this is your case.

```
var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
  var url1 =    'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
    'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=BFTchambers:bft2&' +
    'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures1' +
    '&bbox=' + extent.join(',');
    $.ajax({
      url: url1,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: false
    });
},
strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
maxZoom: 20
})),
});

var vectorSource2 = new ol.source.Vector({
loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
  var url2 =    'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
    'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=BFTchambers:chamber&' +
    'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures2' +
    '&bbox=' + extent.join(',');
$.ajax({
      url: url2,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: false
    });
},
strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
maxZoom: 20
})),
});


/**
 * JSONP WFS callback function.
 * @param {Object} response The response object.
*/
window.loadFeatures1 = function(response) {
console.log("some stuff loaded 1st case");
vectorSource.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
};

window.loadFeatures2 = function(response) {
console.log("some stuff loaded 2nd case");
vectorSource2.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
};
```

Also I am a bit confused why do you use ajax call as long as you provide `callback` function within the url. You may try to remove the callback functions from your urls or remove the ajax calls (from within the loader functions) and just use the callback functions distingusing them as I suggested on my code snip.

Also have a glance to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167231/styling-multiple-wfs-with-openlayers-3#comment248912_167231) and a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/bzpb2vjk/)

Comment: Your code returns type error geoJsonformat.readfeatures1 not a function

Comment: sory that was a typo just remove the 1. Edited my answer

Comment: Yea figured as much. there are no errors now but the points are still not showing up

Comment: Ok few more edits on my original answer. Can you try it?

Comment: Still doesn't load it. But your new version removed the formatWFS which I think I need for the editing function

Comment: If you use it, you can place it within `window.loadFeatures` function. I just want to make it simple so find your problem. Dont you have any errors? Anything in  the log? Does `console.log("some stuff loaded 2nd case");` get fired? if yes can you log the response.

Comment: There are no console errors, both console logs appear but there are no point features showing from the 2nd layer, I wonder if it could have anything to do with the styling? Here's my entire fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Luffydude/2c5o284v/

Comment: Actually it was indeed a styling problem and I fixed it so your code was correct. Problem now is that I can't seem to save any new point that I add. It returns `error "pointWFS.writeTransaction is not a function`

Comment: Within your  `.done(function(response) {` you declare `pointWFS = new ol.format.WFS(),` what is this comma in the end???? This is not correct in terms of js syntax. Just replce comma with semicolun --> `pointWFS = new ol.format.WFS();`

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2c5o284v/1/ you also have naming errors (pointWFS is a format and then you asign a function with the same name) You need to tidy up your code.

Comment: Thank you so much but the problem was solved. The comma doesn't seem to affect anything, it works with and without it. Now I just ran into this minor bug where any point I draw on the map doesn't appear on the map unless I refresh the page (it instantly gets created in the Postgis table tho)